# About dy/dx in application

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

We know that the integral of $\frac{dy}{dx}$ is $y+c$.

However, I've encountered a problem modeling the growth of population, which can be expressed as

$\frac{dP}{dt}=kP$ . where $P$ is the population and $t$ is time

Integrating both sides with regard to dt gives $P(t)= kPt$.

I know this is wrong but can someone clarify for me what exactly did I do wrong?
What is the specific thing in this case preventing me from integrating on both sides?

#### Edit:

Thanks I know it's separation of variables. But I don't really get when to separate variables and when not... Say for example $dy/dt=2r^3$, in this case you can directly integrate both sides with respect to $t$ and get $y(t)=(t^4)/2+C$. Why can't we view ($t^3$) as a certain $P(t)$??

Comment: yea thanks. I know that's the solution but I'm still wondering what is it that prevents me from integrating both sides? Is it because P is a function of t and not a constant?

Comment: You have to separate the variables: $\int \frac1{P}\,  dP=\int k \, dt$

Comment: On the right side of your equation you are assuming $P$ is constant. In general, the integral of $Pdt$ will not be $Pt$.

Comment: You are allowed to integrate both sides of $P'(t) = kP(t)$, however this will not help you much as you cannot evaluate the integral of $\int kP(t){\rm d}t$ without knowing $P(t)$ (which is what you are trying to solve for). So nothing is preventing you from doing this, it's just a dead end towards solving for $P(t)$.

Comment: @Winther yea thanks that's what I wanted to know!

Answer (score 1):

If you integrate directly you get
$$\int dp=\int kp dt$$
$$\implies p(t)=k\int p dt$$
you can't evaluate the integral you are stuck

Thats why we need to separate variables here
$$\frac {dp}p=kdt$$
After integration
$$\int \frac {dp}p=k\int dt \implies \ln p=kt+C$$
$$p=Ce^{kt}$$

With your example with y ,note that you have no y on the right side of the equation like the equation with p. These two differential equations are different.You have y on one side and t on the other side already. Thats what we tried to have with the equation with p(t).
$$\frac {dy}{dt}=2t^3$$
$$\implies \int dy=2\int t^3dt$$
$$y(t)=\frac {t^4}2+C$$

Comment: ok thank you very much! Yea it's because we don't know what p is in that right hand side integral. I get it now :D

Comment: @Shuo yes the two equation differ in that yes the second with y is already separated

Answer (score 0):

> Say for example $dy/dt=2\cdot t^3$, in this case you can directly integrate
>   both sides with regard to t and get $y(t)=(t^4)/2+C$

Technically you have to separate the variables as well. Multiplying both sides by $dt$

$dy=2\cdot t^3 \, dt$

Integrating both sides

$\int \, dy=\int 2\cdot t^3 \, dt$

$y+c_1=\frac{t^4}{2}+c_2$

$y=\frac{t^4}{2}+c_2-c_1$

$C=c_2-c_1$

$y=\frac{t^4}{2}+C$

Comment: well in this case I think you don't need separating variable... but you can do it that way. thanks.

Comment: @Shuo I still would say that technically you have to separate the variables. To integrate you need $dy$ on the RHS and $dt$ on the LHS. If you don´t separate them you have $ y^{'}=2\cdot t^3 \, \Rightarrow dy/dt=  2\cdot t^3 \, \Rightarrow \int dy/dt=  \int 2\cdot t^3$. This doesn´t seem right to me. $\int$ and $\, dx$ appears always together.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this first order differential equation, like the other posters have said, by separation of variables.

\begin{align*}
\frac{\mathrm{d}P}{\mathrm{d}t} &= k P(t) \\
\frac{\mathrm{d}P}{P(t)} &= k \,\mathrm{d}t \\
\int \frac{1}{P(t)} \mathrm{d}P &= k\int\mathrm{d}t \\
\ln{P(t)} + c_1 &= k\cdot t + c_2 \\
\ln{P(t)} &= k\cdot t + c \\
P(t) &= e^{kt + c} \\
P(t) &= e^{kt} + e^c \\
P(t) &= e^{kt} + C
\end{align*}

Hence, we have an implicit solution to this ODE. You can see more about this method [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_variables).

Comment: ok thank you a lot!